# Testing MS-CAPI CSP, signature fails even with WinDbg kernel debugging

Tags: windows, windbg, cryptoapi, mscapi

Trying to test a new CSP under Win 7.  Set the boot config to allow kernel debug, run `WndDbg` and select file:kernel debug and set to local.  Attempting to use signtool with my new CSP still results in signature failure check.  Environment is:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free

System Model:              Dell System Inspiron N7110
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7 GenuineIntel ~2501 Mhz
BIOS Version:              Dell Inc.          A09, 11/18/2011
Windows Directory:         C:\Windows
System Directory:          C:\Windows\system32
```

---

Any thoughts on why the presence of the kernel debugger is not preventing the signature check on the test CSP?  Does that setup only work in a remote-debug environment?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a remote debugger to disable the signature check.

There are [various mechanisms such as 1394 (FireWire) or Serial Cable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by which you can can connect the second computer for remote debugging.

If your CSP can run in a VM, then that would be an option too if you just have the one machine.